# Существует ли CMS с такими возможностями?

Tags: php, cms

Собственно задался следующим вопросом, существует ли такая CMS, которая позволяет создавать модели данных через админку, т.е. по факту чтобы расширение было без разработки расширений?
Или хотя бы вариант как у 1С Битрикс, с возможностью добавлять поля для компонентов, и расширение путём копирования компонентов.
Понятное дело 1С Битрикс, это не то решение которое нужно, просто схожий функционал у других CMS не встречал.

Comment: Да, на ларе есть прикольная cms https://voyager.devdojo.com/

Comment: cms voyager как вариант, пощупать надо будет, а что ещё есть?

Comment: С некоторого момента легче начать программировать, чем пытаться этого не делать: https://www.solmediaco.com/blog/dont-believe-the-no-code-lie

Comment: Sergei Kirjanov, не спорю, но комментарий к теме вопроса отношения не имеет. Если есть инструмент, то и задачи под него явно имеются. Есть нечего по существу сказать, то лучше промолчать.